# WPF Enable Highlight, Copy, and Paste inside a Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have a list of strings that I want to display on a menu. I used a Listbox and it works just that it won't let me highlight or copy/paste.

Here is my XAML

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="500"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="500"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="450"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="318"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>



    <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="uiOCRData" />



</Grid>
```

Heres what I have in C#

```
List<string> lines = new List<string>();
uiOCRData.ItemsSource = lines;
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Use textbox as Listbox.ItemTemplate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a `ListBox.ItemTemplate` so that you can include a control inside your `ListBox`.

Since you want to be able to select text etc., the best option is to use a `TextBox`.

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="0" Name="uiOCRData">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=.}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

### EDIT

Let's say you want to bind to a list of some class objects instead of a simple list of strings. Say your class looks like this:

```
public class Data
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can bind to any one of chosen `Properties` of the class like this:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="0" Name="uiOCRData">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: When I used this nothing came up inside my ui. I did     <TextBox Text="{Binding Path = lines}" />

Comment: If you're using a `List<string>` as your `ItemsSource`, then the binding has to be exactly as I've shown: `<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=.}"/>`